# Observation and deduction about a stick

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, laws-of-physics

Given a horizontal stick AB and a string, of course a stick that is hang on the string in its center of mass is in equilibrium. This is a fact that we take as rule because we can observe it, right? I mean, this is not a fact that we can deduce by maths. Now, if you have for example two external and vertical downward forces, say $\vec F_1$ and $\vec F_2$. The first acts on $A$ and the second on $B$. Can we take as rule of observation that in order to have equilibrium we have to put the string on the point given by $d_1:d_2=F_2:F_1$ ? Or can we deduce it by maths?

Comment: What a real stick does can only be found out by observation, what theoretical forces acting on a theoretical stick do can be deduced mathematically.

Comment: yes, the equilibrium point can be deducted theoretically

Comment: What does your physics text book say about this?

Comment: Sorry but I know that if we write the equations for the equilibrium we find a point $P$ on the stick where I should put the string. But we find also $\vec T=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$ (do not consider the weight of the stick).  We do not have control on $T$, and suppose I give you a very robust string: what guarantee to us that if I put the string in $P$ then the tension will be exactly $\vec F_1+\vec F_2$? This is something that our experience suggests right? I mean it's like the fact that if I put an object on a very strong table it will be in the equilibrium right?

Comment: I mean, how can we predict the behavior of the tension of the string?

Comment: What do you mean by "predict"?

Comment: I mean, as I wrote above: What guarantees that if we put a robust string on the point $P$ then the tension $T$ will be exactly $\vec F_1+\vec F_2$?

Comment: @Richard: Newton's second law. If the forces acting on the stick cancel out, as well as all torques, then by Newton's second the stick must be motionless, both translationally and rotationally.

Comment: My problem is the converse: I just put quietly the string in the point $P$ of the stick. How can I be sure that the forest acting on the stick cancel out? see also the comments under the answer.

Comment: Hi @lucas: It is recommended to avoid the [law-of-phys tag](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/laws-of-physics/info), since the tag is prone to be overused: Every post on Phys.SE is in principle about the laws of physics!

Comment: @Qmechanic OK, sure. But, current question really relates to that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a horizontal stick AB and a string, of course a stick that is hang on the string in its center of mass is in equilibrium. This is a **fact** that we take as **rule** because **we can observe it**, right?

We never can understand what is the fact. Because we never can discover **true** laws of physics (or nature) unless we ask the creative of the nature and as far as I know, no one has seen him. Hence, I correct your sentence as below:

This is a fact that we take as rule because **we hope it be**.

No one cannot prove laws of physics like laws of Newton for instance. What we can do is acceptance or rejection of them. We have accepted that if the net force acting on a body with constant mass is $\vec F$ then its acceleration will be $\vec a=\frac {\vec F}m$. We cannot prove or even observe it but we hope that it is true and we build machines, airplanes, etc. by it without **certainty** of its correctness. This is why human is a wonderful creature! He lives with things that never knows their correctness.

Comment: ok but once we have accepted laws like the conditions of equilibrium, why should we accept that putting the string in $P$ implies $\vec T=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$? Again, we accept this because of many observations? I mean, in general we study an object that we can observe and we base the equations on it. Here, for example, I'd say : I see the situation of my question and everything in in equilibrium. So  I write equations for the equilibrium. These give to me that the point $P$ must be $lF_2/(F_1+F_2)$.

Comment: But what about the converse? If I have a stick and a robust string and someone tells me: Put this objects in equilibrium, everybody would put the string in $P=lF_2/(F_1+F_2)$, but this does not imply that $\vec T=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$ mathematically. So why everybody would be sure about equilibrium?

Comment: I say, they aren't sure! They hope  and have accepted that stick will be in equilibrium if they put the string in $\frac{lF_2}{F_1+F_2}$. In addition, equations of the equilibrium that we have accepted, are $\Sigma \vec F=\vec 0$ and $\Sigma \vec M=\vec 0$. We have accepted both of them.

Comment: ok but why they accepted that stick will be in equilibrium if they put the string in $lF_2/(F_1+F_2)$? Only from this we don't have a $\textbf{mathematical proof}$ that $\vec T=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$. We can deduce the tension only if we $\textbf{observe}$ the objects. So are they sure because of their experiences?

Comment: Note: none of their accepted laws imply, $\textbf{without observing}$,  that $\vec T=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$.

Comment: lucas what do you think about it?

Comment: When a stick is hang on a string, do you see any force? I personally, never have seen a **force** yet and I cannot show a force for my grandmother. But, she knows that where she must tie the string so that stick be in equilibrium. She never knows that there is a **concept** called force. And she don't need to indicate which equation imply which. All of what you are talking about, are **our conventions**. We don't know the truth and never can know, so we **guess** it and **hope** it be true.

Comment: But is it like when I put a box on a table isn't it? I know that the table will act a reaction force $\vec R$ on the box such that the box will be in equilibrium. I cannot deduce this $\textbf{behavior of the table}$ by maths right? I think these are same arguments. Of course in this comment you can take the laws of physics as accepted.

Comment: I think you got confused about difference between physics and mathematics. Mathematics is an instrument. We use it to live better by our accepted laws. We cannot prove those laws by math. We can use math by considering our laws to improve our life. I have a question: You know that you see things around. Can you deduce it by math? Can you prove it by math for me?

Comment: Of course I can't. I agree. But so am I right if I say that it is an accepted law that if I put the string in the point $P=lF_2/(F_1+F_2)$ the tension is automatically equal to $\vec F_1+\vec F_2$?

Comment: **My** accepted laws about equilibrium are $\Sigma \vec F=\vec 0$ and $\Sigma \vec M=\vec 0$ and **according them**, I can say if the stick is in equilibrium, then **certainly** $\vec T=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$ and $P=\large{\frac{lF_2}{F_1+F_2}}$.

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your patience and yes, I have evidently confusion between physics and its use of maths. I hope my comment above will be the last one.

Comment: So if I do the converse, namely just putting the string in $P$ in order to have the equilibrium (namely to satisfy automatically the accepted laws about equilibrium), I will do a simple $\textbf{guess}$ that $\textbf{actually works}$? And the $\textbf{reason}$ will be just that $\textbf{this is how the nature acts}$?

Comment: Yes, but this is not a **simple** guess. Lots of works have been done for that. A lot of people (we don't know most of them!) have tried for that. It is simple in your opinion because you have learnt it from childhood. But as I said before, I cannot teach it to an uneducated adult person easily.

Comment: Ok so your " yes " is for both the questions of the last my comment right? I ask because I added the second one after few minutes. Then I have finished.

Comment: The reason will be just that **we think** the nature acts such this.